# Generate .bond files from C# data contracts

Tags: c#, bond

I have written C # data contracts with MS Bond attributes. It's work fine for C# only data exchange. But I can't get IDL or AST schema (.bond file) for generating these data contracts in other languages (с++, python).

Bond API support only "Runtime schema" generation, but the bond compiler can't make AST or IDL schema from Runtime schema.

Avro and Protobuf.NET support "schema generation" (Serializer.GetProto()) in runtime.

How can I solve this problem with Bond API and without developing "AutoCodeGen" or "AutoBondGen"?

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

As of January 2018, such functionality does not exist.

There's an [open feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/issues/779) that looking for contributors to provide such functionality.